# How does list versioning impact storage capacity?

Tags: versioning, storage

Interested in turning on list versioning (not document versioning) in SharePoint and wanted to know the impact it has on storage. Does it take up much storage?
Thanks!

Comment: Version of sharepoint? On Prem or online?

Answer (score 1):

List versioning or in fact document versioning will take similar space which is equal to your list item/document. Ideally it would depend on what is size of your list items based on number of columns/type of columns and data in each columns...

Though its impact will be very less..list item will not take too much space...use SharePoint List Usage and Statistics to identify size of your list...

Thought below is written for documents...and same should be case with list item...
Sharepoint stores a complete copy of each version of your document in the database. It means that 5 versions of a 4 mb document takes 20 mb.

Comment: "Sharepoint stores a complete copy of each version of your document in the database. It means that 5 versions of a 4 mb document takes 20 mb" - in 2010 and earlier that is the case, shredded storage in 2013 reduces this.

Comment: Thanks Eric for clarifying...is there any new indication from Microsoft on how much it would be considering shredded storage ?

Comment: " In core collaborative use case scenarios where historical versioning is enabled, Shredded Storage
can reduce overall data storage requirements an estimated 30-40% through ensuring that only the BLOB partition (chunk)
associated with the change is updated." via https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39719